# Obtain final non-matching piece of string after re.match()

Tags: python, regex

I want to break a string out in to multiple pieces such that each line contains at least 12 characters, but also that the line breaks on a `,`.  I'm using `re.match()` to do this with the regex `(.{12}[^,]*, )` and it works fine except that I don't have the non-matching piece at the end of the string.  How can I obtain this piece as well?

To give an example, the input string:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0, 1 2 3 4 5, 1 2 3, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2, 1, 2`

Should result in the following groups:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0,
1 2 3 4 5, 1 2 3,
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2,
1, 2
```

The above regex provides all but the last group.  Online version of the regex with sample data is available [here](http://pythex.org/?regex=(.%7B12%7D%5B%5E%2C%5D*%2C%20)&test_string=1%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%2C%201%202%203%204%205%2C%201%202%203%2C%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%2C%201%2C%202&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `re.findall`:

```
s = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0, 1 2 3 4 5, 1 2 3, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2, 1, 2'
print(re.findall(".{12}[^,]*, |.*", s))
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your `.{12}[^,]*,`  regex is that it requires exactly 12 any characters and then 0 or more characters other than a comma up to the closest comma and a space, while you need to match 1 to 12 any characters with optional comma+space at the end.

Here is the regex:

```
.{1,12}[^,]*(?:, )?
 ^^^        ^^^^^^^ - making comma+space optional with (?:...)?
  ^^ - matching 1 to 12 symbols greedily
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rM3zC3/1)

[IDEONE demo:](http://ideone.com/m0mRUo)

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(.{1,12}[^,]*(?:, )?)')
test_str = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0, 1 2 3 4 5, 1 2 3, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2, 1, 2"
print (p.findall(test_str))
```

Result: `['1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0, ', '1 2 3 4 5, 1 2 3, ', '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2, ', '1, 2']`